# Mongo DB Push to Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Working on a project that uses MongoDB as a database. I'm stuck on trying to get an array of objects I have to update. Here is the schema:

```
roundData : {
                playsArray : [ 
                    {
                        player1 : {
                            card1 : 1,
                            card2 : 2
                        },
                        player2 : {
                            card1 : 0,
                            card2 : 0
                        }
                    },
                ],
```

So basically I want a single array that holds an object within that object are two objects.

Plays Array [ object1, object2] where object 1 would be {player 1 : {card1 : 0, card2 : 0}}, {player 2 : {card1 : 0, card2 : 0}}.

Every time I try to write an updateOne function, it at best only updates player 1 or it seperates player 1 and player 2 as two items in the array. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong on the formating?

Here's my current code:

```
const gameData = await GameData.updateOne({ gameId: gameIdInput }, { $push: { "matchData.roundData.playsArray": { $each : [ {"player1" : {"card1" : 0, "card2" :0} }, {"player2" : {"card1" : 0, "card2" :0} } ] } } } );
```

This works, but it pushes player 1 and player 2 into the array separately so that the array becomes [ player 1/2 objects, player 1 objects, player 2 objects ].

Comment: Please provide a complete MongoDB document. From the provided document, based on your query, it should have `matchData` wrap the `roundData` document.

Comment: Without `matchData.` in query, it should able to append the new object into `roundData.playsArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I was missing [ ] around the object in a previous version without $each. Leaving here for solution if anyone finds it helpful.

```
const gameData = await GameData.updateOne({ gameId: gameIdInput }, { $push: { "matchData.roundData.playsArray": [ {"player1" : {"card1" : 0, "card2" :0} }, {"player2" : {"card1" : 0, "card2" :0} } ]  } } );
```